# sql count how many times 2 values share a third value

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables which i can join on a common id.  however, one table has people names and the other table has company names.

[`people table`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZwcc.png)

[`company table`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b1ha.png)

how can i produce a query result where I can get a count of how many times each person shares the same id as each company?

Comment: read up on MySQL JOINs and make better tables.  Is there ever only one Sarah in your company? What if one Sarah belongs to 2 companies and another Sarah belongs to one company?

Comment: in this example, only one sarah exist.  i am just not sure how to run a return a count how many time a person and company share the same id.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your table data looks odd.  but here goes

```
SELECT p.person,COUNT(*) as share_count
FROM people p
INNER JOIN company c
ON c.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.person
```

result

```
person  share_count
dave    3
mark    4
sara    3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aba04/3

OR if you want to group by p.id and p.person

```
SELECT p.id,p.person,COUNT(*) as share_count
FROM people p
INNER JOIN company c
ON c.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id,p.person
```

result

```
id  person  share_count
1   dave    1
1   sara    1
2   mark    2
2   sara    2
3   dave    2
3   mark    2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aba04/5

**UPDATE** to divide share_count by (COUNT of distinct person)

```
SELECT p.person,COUNT(*) as share_count,COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person) FROM people) as percent
FROM people p
INNER JOIN company c
ON c.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.person
```

Comment: thanks a bunch.  this is really helpful.  the only issue is that the actually tables have 5M and 3M records respectively so the query takes a while.  any shot you could recommend how to add a final column that shows what percent that the share_count is of the "person_count".  I tried `sum((SELECT `share_count`) / count(p.person) as percent`

Comment: check my bottom of my answer for dividing by number of distinct person.

Comment: Also if you CREATE INDEX on ids the query should execute faster